# Gap based priority queue / sorting?

Tags: arrays, sorting, priority-queue

I'm looking for a priority queue based on a sorted array with *gaps*.  Gaps could be used whenever a place was needed to put in an object. Gaps were be periodically "spread out" in amortized time.

I've seen an article like that but I've lost it and can't find it any more. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is related to the  [Librarian Sort](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_sort).